# CrosspagePostBack with Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have PageA with some controls (txtFooBar) on it, and a button with PostBackUrl set to PageB.

In PageB I can write

```
Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtFooBar")
```

and get at my values.

Now suppose I am using forms authentication, and PageB is protected, and I'm not initially logged in, so when I press the button on PageA I go to the login page, and proceed to PageB once I am logged in.

Now, Page.PreviousPage is null.

Is there any way I can get at the values from PageA? I am trying to avoid using the Session object to manage state here, as I need the application to be highly scalable and would prefer to avoid session affinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by redirect from login page, while PreviousPage supported only over POST.
So review following ways:

- create inplace login control on the page A, so user could be logged in without redirect
- create your own login form, that instead of redirect uses Server.Transfer to pageB (note that to auth user only FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie is needed)